# Find in array by id

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [email] => email1@account.com
            [fullname] => name1
            [phone] => phone
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [email] => email2@account.com
            [fullname] => name2
            [phone] => phone
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 40
            [email] => email@account.com
            [fullname] => namex
            [phone] => phone
        )
)
```

How can I return array by id using php?

For example: id = 40; Return:

```
[id] => 40
[email] => email@account.com
[fullname] => namex
[phone] => phone
```

Thanks.

Comment: If you want to search the array by `id`, why don't you use the `id` as key for the array?

Comment: You could sort the array by ID, then use a binary search to find the item you want. Or, you could use the ID as the key to make a hash map if you will not support duplicates. You could also simply iterate the entire array, and look for the element with the ID you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$return = 0;
foreach($array as $row) {
   if (40 == $row['id']) {
      $return = $row;
      break;
   }
}

var_dump($return);
```

Answer (score 3):

Create function for this as below,

```
function arraysearch($array, $id)
{
   foreach($array as $key => $value)
   {
      if ( $value['id'] == $id ) {
         return $key;
      }
   }
   return false;
}
```

And call it as below,

```
arraysearch($yourarray, 40);
```

Comment: and why is that down vote

Comment: @AmalMurali No, this function reaturns `FALSE` if no entry with the given ID was found; this is a good implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this, its just a pseudo code.

```
$matchId    = 40;
foreach( $array as $key => $each ){
    if( $each['id'] == $matchId ){
        $result = $array[$key];
    }
}
return $result;
```

Comment: You should `break` the foreach when you find result; like Alexandr did in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a snippet from a class that implement the [interface \Iterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php), it could be edited to work with any arrays if `$this->data` is replaced by the array (maybe from a third argument):

```
/**
 * Find an item by one of it's properties from the internal data array.
 *
 * @param string $property
 * @param mixed $value
 * @return mixed Return NULL if no matching item was found; return FALSE if no such property exists.
 */
public function getByProperty( $property, $value )
{
    reset( $this->data );
    $anArrayEntryFromData = current( $this->data );
    if( !isset( $anArrayEntryFromData[$property] ) )
    {
        /* there is no such $property */
        throw new \UnexpectedValueException( sprintf( '%s::%s() – There is no property "%s" in the internal data array for this collection. The available properties for this collection are: %s', get_called_class(), __FUNCTION__, $property, implode( ', ', array_keys( $anArrayEntryFromData ) ) ) );
    }

    foreach( $this->data as $valueArray )
    {
        if( is_scalar( $value ) && !is_numeric( $value ) )
        {
            if( strtolower( $valueArray[$property] ) == strtolower( $value ) )
            {
                return $valueArray[$property];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if( $valueArray[$property] == $value )
            {
                return $valueArray[$property];
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Usage:

```
$iterator->getByProperty( 'id', 40 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 $array = array (
    "0" => array
        (
            "id" => "1",
            "email" => "email1@account.com",
            "fullname" => "name1",
            "phone" => "phone"
        ),
    "1" => array
        (
            "id" => 2,
            "email" => "email2@account.com",
            "fullname" => "name2",
            "phone" => "phone"
        ),
    "2" => array
        (
            "id" => 40,
            "email" => "email@account.com",
            "fullname" => "namex",
            "phone" => "phone"
        )
);


$id = 40;
print_r(getArray($array, $id));

function getArray($array, $id)
{
    $result = array();
    foreach( $array as $key => $value ){
        if( $value['id'] == $id ){
            $result = $value;
                    break;
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
$data=your array;
foreach($data as $key=>$each)
{
    if($each['id']=="40")
    {
        return $data[$key];
    }
}
```

i have given a static example here.